# Do I need to include dialogues and JFrames in a class diagram?

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I'm creating a project documentation for a *Question management and generating system* and need to draw class diagrams from that system.

My question:

I have a lot of dialogues and frames since I'm programming in Java. Should I include the GUIs with the diagram and relate them to other control classes?

Comment: Depends on the audience.

Comment: They are my doctors in university :D

Comment: They gave you that work. But it's some real world simulation. In that real world: what would be the audience of your model?

Comment: Doctors and teachers to generate there exams :D

Comment: In that case: please them and include the GUI.

Comment: Thank you :D i already included i appreciate your help